# Mathematical function for string similarity score

Tags: math, string-comparison

I'm working on a string similarity algorithm, and was thinking on how to give a score between 0 and 1 when comparing two strings. The two variables for this function are the Levenshtein distance *D*: (added, removed and changed characters) and the maximum length of the two strings *L* (but you could also take the average).

My initial algorithm was just `1-D/L` but this gave too high scores for short strings, e.g. 'tree' and 'bee' would get a score of 0.5, and too low scores for longer strings which have more in common even if half of the characters is different.

Now I'm looking for a mathematical function that can output a better score. I wasn't able to come up with one, so I sketched this height map of a 3D plot (*L* is x and *D* = y).

[image: Example height map]

Does anyone know how to convert such a graph to an equation, if I would be better off to just create a lookup table or if there is an existing solution?